# Concentration for $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \psi(x_i^\top u)$, for $y_1,\ldots,y_n \sim \{\pm 1\}$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ uniform iid on hypersphere

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, random-walks, measure-concentration, learning-theory

Let $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ be drawn iid uniformly from $\{\pm 1\}$ and let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be drawn iid uniformly from the unit-sphere $(d-1)$-dimensional sphere $\mathbb S_{d-1}$, and independently from the $y_i$'s. Fix a $u \in \mathbb S_{d-1}$. Finally, let $\psi:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a $1$-Lipschitz continuous function.

> **Question.**
> *What is a good concentration inequality for the sum $f(u):=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\psi(x_i^\top u)$ ?*

My ultimate goal is to bound the supremum $f^* := \sup_{u \in \mathbb S_{d-1}} f(u)$ of the empirical process $(f(u))_{u \in \mathbb S_{d-1}}$. I figured out if I could get a high-probability bound for each $f(u)$ which holds with probability $1-Ae^{-Bd}$, then I could use a covering argument to bound $f^*$.

> **Question 2.** *Maybe there is a direct way to bound $f^*$ using empirical process theory ?*

### Some observations

Using properties of Rademacher sums, one may compute
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb E_{y_1,\ldots,y_n}[f^*] &= \mathbb E_{y_1,\ldots,y_n}\sup_{u \in \mathbb S_{d-1}}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\psi(x_i^\top u) \le  \mathbb E_{y_1,\ldots,y_n}\sup_{u \in \mathbb S_{d-1}}\sum_{i=1}^n y_ix_i^\top u\\
&\le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i\|^2} = \sqrt{n}.
\end{split}
$$

---

### Update: partial solution

Suppose further that $\psi$ is twice continuously-differentiable with except on a set $E$ of Lebesgue measure $0$, and $\|\psi''\|_\infty := \sup_{r \in \mathbb R\setminus E}|\psi''(r)| < \infty$. For fixed $u \in \mathbb S_{d-1}$, defined $z_i := x_i^\top u$. It is easy to see that $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ are iid from a distribution which satisfies a log-sobolev inequality with constant $L=1/\sqrt{d}$. Moreover, $f(u) = G(z) := \sum_{i=1}^n \psi(z_i)$. By the Adamczak-Wolff generalization ([see slide 22](https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/722/wolffslides.pdf) or so) of the classical Hanson-Wright inequality, we have
$$
\mathbb P(|G(z) - \mathbb E[G(z)]| \ge t) \le 2 \exp\left(-C\frac{t^2}{L^2\|\mathbb E [\nabla G(z)]\|^2 + L^4A_{HS}} \land \frac{t}{L^2 A_{op}}\right),
$$
where $A_{HS}$ and $A_{op}$ nonnegative constants such that
$\|D^2 G(z)\|_{HS} \le A_{HS}$ and $\|D^2 G(z)\|_{op} \le A_{op}$ for all $z \in \mathbb R^n$.

Now, define $a:=\mathbb E[\psi(z_1)]$, $b:=\mathbb E[\psi'(z_1)]$, and $c:=\|\psi''\|_\infty$. By direct computation we have $\mathbb E[G(z)] = na$. Also, for any $s \in \mathbb R^n$, we compute the gradient of $G$ as $\nabla G(s) = (\psi'(s_1),\ldots,\psi'(s_n))$ and its hessian as $D^2 G(s) = \mbox{diag}(\psi''(s_1),\ldots,\psi''(s_n))$. Thus

- $\|\mathbb E[\nabla G(s)]\|^2 = nb^2$.
- $\|D^2 G(s)\|_{op} = \max_{1 \le i \le n} |\psi''(s_i)| \le c$.
- $\|D^2 G(s)\|_{HS}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (\psi''(s_i))^2 \le n\|\psi''\|_\infty^2 := nc^2$.

Collecting the pieces, we have
$$
\mathbb P(|G(z) - na| \ge t) \le 2\exp(-Cd\eta(t)),
\tag{1}
$$
where $\eta(t) := \dfrac{1}{d}\cdot \left(\dfrac{t^2}{d^{-1}nb^2 + d^{-2}nc^2} \land \dfrac{t}{d^{-1} c}\right) = \dfrac{t^2}{n(b^2+c^2/d)} \land \dfrac{t}{c}$.

### Examples

**Quadratic activation function $\psi(r):= r^2/2$.** A direct computation reveals that $a=\mathbb E[z_1^2/2] = 1/(2d)$; $b=\mathbb E[z_1] = 0$; $c=1$. Thus $\eta(t) = \dfrac{t^2}{n/d} \land t = \dfrac{d}{n}\cdot t^2 \land t$, and we have the simplified bound
$$
\mathbb P(|G(z) - n/(2d)| \ge t) \le \begin{cases}2\exp(-Ctd),&\mbox{ if }t \ge n/d,\\2\exp(-Ct^2d/n),&\mbox{ else.}\end{cases}
$$
Take $\tau \in (0,n]$ and $t=\sqrt{n\tau}/d \le n/d$, we have
$$
\mathbb P(|G(z) - n/(2d)| \ge \sqrt{n\tau}/d) \le 2\exp(-Ct^2/n)= 2\exp(-C\tau). \tag{2}
$$

Let $n^+ := \#\{i \in [n] \mid y_i=+1\}$ and define $n^-$ analogously. Hoeffding's inequality gives
$$
\mathbb P(|n^+-n^-| \le \sqrt{n\tau}) \ge 1 - \exp(-\Omega(\tau)).
$$
Thus, writing $f(u) = \sum_{y_i=+1}\psi(z_i) - \sum_{y_i=-1}\psi(z_i)$ and appying (2) to each each of the two terms, we obtain that w.p $1-\exp(-\Omega(\tau))$,
$$
\begin{split}
|f(u)| &= |\sum_{y_i = + 1}\psi(z_i) - \sum_{y_i = -1}\psi(z_i)|\\
&= \left|(\sum_{y_i = + 1}\psi(z_i) - n^+/(2d))- (\sum_{y_i = -1}\psi(z_i) - n^-/(2d)) + (n^+-n^-)/(2d)\right|\\
&\le \mathcal O(\sqrt{n\tau}/d) + |n^+-n^-|/(2d) = \mathcal O(\sqrt{n\tau}/d)
\end{split}
$$

**Piecewise linear activation function.** Here $a=\mathbb E[\psi(z_1)] = \mathcal O(1/\sqrt{d})$, $b = \mathbb E[\psi'(z_1)] = \mathcal O(1)$; and $c=\|\psi''\|_\infty = 0$. Thus $\eta(t) = \Omega(t^2/n)$ and plugging into (1) yields
$$
\mathbb P(|G(z) - n/\sqrt{2\pi d}| \ge t) \le 2\exp(-Ct^2d/n).
$$
Taking $t=\Omega(\sqrt{n\tau/d})$ then gives
$\mathbb P(|G(z) - \mathcal O(n/\sqrt{d})| \gtrsim \sqrt{n\tau/d}) \le 2\exp(-C\tau)$, and using an analogous decomposition strategy as in the previous scenario, we obtain that
$$
\mathbb P(|f(u)| \lesssim \sqrt{n\tau/d}) \ge 1-\exp(-\Omega(\tau)).
$$